# How do I run linear regression for every combination of col1, col2 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have some time series stock market data that I am testing out linear regression with. I want to run a separate linear regression for each combination of the market, ticker. What is the most efficient way to run that?

Most of the examples that I have seen show how to apply a ml algorithm on one particular stock ticker, but I would like run against all at the same time.

something like:

```py
for curr_market in df.market:
   df2 = df[df.market==curr_market] # get subset of records in this market
   for curr_ticker in df2.ticket:
       # run LR from sklearn
```

Is there a better way to create a model for each market, ticker combination?

Comment: Please clarify your question and share a reproducible example that includes a representation of your data set and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Because you are asking for advice on technique, and not troubleshooting a specific error, your question seems to be fine as is and so I gave an upvote.